# jQuery click/touch events won't fire in mobile (inline element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I have a span element which when clicked/touched should trigger certain actions in jQuery.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<span id="" class="dwr_icon_location locationElementBtn"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Location Button
  $(document).on("click touchstart",".locationElementBtn", function(){
      $(".locationBtn").toggleClass("active");

      // Displaying location window in the proper bar
      var locationBtn   = $(this).parent(".locationBtn");
      var locationStngs = $("#locationStngs");

      // if locationStngs doesn't exist in the current bar
      if(!locationBtn.children("#locationStngs").length){
        locationBtn.append(locationStngs);
      }
  });
});
```

The problem is that the event is never fired *in mobile*, despite other elements with jQuery listeners attached to them working just fine. No errors display on the console either. Everything seems to work in desktop, by the way.

I am aware this question has been asked repeatedly before, but in this instance I just don't seem to find a solution. Any insight into how to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Here it does not work on the non mobile site either (Chrome 39).  Only if I add a border around the `.locationElementBtn` it will work, as of that I'm pretty sure it is related to your styling, probably having a `block` style element in an `inline` or something similar.

Comment: @t.niese I'm having a similar problem. Do I understand well that ontouchstart doesn't work with `display: inline;`? Because it's the only thing that seems to matter. If I change it to, for example, `display: block;` - it works. How can I display a div inline and make ontouchstart respond? I need to have it without a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding

```
display:inline-block
```

to `.locationElementBtn`. It seems that link hitspaces arent quite so visible for **inline** (span) elements on mobile, thus the jQuery events aren't fired. It probably has something to do with the element containing a font icon.

Thanks to [t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese) for the hint!